# Merged accounts on multiple sites, but not all completed

Tags: support, linked-accounts, network-profile, merge-accounts

I recently had two accounts merged ([old](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148067/animesh), [new](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539542/steeluser)); now my accounts on the following sites all use the same OpenID:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539542/)
- [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/157007/)
- [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8314/)
- [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3729/)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/7566/)
- [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4605/)
- [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/3789/)
- [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/4711/)
- [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/32344/steeluser)
- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/10698/)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/3086/)
- **[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/users/15067/steeluser)**
- **[Super User](https://superuser.com/users/4321/steeluser)**

Most of them are associated with the network profile [519a3b7d-a883-4788-ad1c-2333e2657fd4](https://stackexchange.com/users/519a3b7d-a883-4788-ad1c-2333e2657fd4?tab=accounts), but the last two in bold aren't; they're on the profile [3166c184-56ba-4b54-968d-e8b08855fc9a](https://stackexchange.com/users/3166c184-56ba-4b54-968d-e8b08855fc9a), even though they all use the same OpenID and I can login to them the same way.

How can I get this fixed so all my accounts will be under a single network profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried clearing your associations on Unix and Linux and somehow broke it worse, but then [Rebecca Chernoff](https://web.archive.org/web/20131205225750/http://meta.stackoverflow.com:80/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff) looked into it and did some sort of magic. I see all 13 accounts pointing to [519a3b7d-a883-4788-ad1c-2333e2657fd4](https://stackexchange.com/users/519a3b7d-a883-4788-ad1c-2333e2657fd4) now.

In the future, you should be able to fix this yourself unless it's extremely broken. On a given [accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/157007/?tab=accounts) tab, at the bottom you should see a "Clear all Stack Exchange account associations" button. Click that and wait 15 minutes for the change to propagate. Then you should see a list of all your accounts, with an "associate with other sites" button:

[image: Screenshot of the button]

Clicking that should associate all your accounts under a single network profile